# Pasar Datos entre controladores dentro de un tab bar IOS swift3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Hola estoy comenzando a programar en Swift3 en iOS y necesito hacer un tab bar pero nose como puedo pasar datos entre los controladores , alguien puede ayudarme?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Ya intentaste persistir los datos en uno de los view controllers y luego extraerlos en donde los necesitas

Otra opción es crear un singleton y hacer solo la consulta del objeto del singleton

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una clase singleton que uses desde los dos controladores o recuperar la instancia controlador desde el tab y poner el valor a la propiedad que deseas de esta manera....

self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1] donde items? es un array de ViewControllers... y el número corresponde de izquierda a derecha el lugar que ocupa. Por consiguiente la primera pantalla corresponde al 0
suerte

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar una propiedad (o varias) en el `UITabBarController`, y ésta será accesible desde cada uno de los hijos a través de la propiedad existente en todos los UIViewControllers `open var tabBarController: UITabBarController? { get }` (siempre que tengan un `UITabBarController` configurado como padre).

Para ello necesitarás crear una subclase de `UITabBarController`, y asignar las clases correspondientes en el `Storyboard`.

Una demo podría ser la siguiente:

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

   var myString: String?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

   }
}

class MyChildViewController1: UIViewController {

   var myTabBar: MyTabBarController? {
       return tabBarController as? MyTabBarController
   }

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)

      print("stringValue: \(myTabBar?.myString ?? "nil")")

      myTabBar?.myString = "Value of controller 1"
   }
}


class MyChildViewController2: UIViewController {

   var myTabBar: MyTabBarController? {
       return tabBarController as? MyTabBarController
   }

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)

      print("stringValue: \(myTabBar?.myString ?? "nil")")

      myTabBar?.myString = "Value of controller 1"
   }
}
```

Según vayas cambiando de un `tab` a otro, verás como se imprime el valor asignado en el controlador anterior. (el primer print imprimirá `nil`)